# How to inject view model with scope using sharedview model koin android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope

need little bit clarity on one thing, right now working on a flow where I've two view model and one is dependent on other , to handle that thing I tried injecting both view models in my Base Activity the problem I faced, with this approach. Every time when I try to access those view model, Base Activity was returning  me new instances, is there any way I can manage scope of that view model so I can easily access its properties without adding extra Api calls.

**Module Class**

```
    val homeModule= module {
      
        single { HomeDispatcher(get(), get()) }
        viewModel { HomeViewModel (get()) }
    }

**Main Activity**

    import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel

        class NotificationActivity : BaseActivity() {
        
           private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by inject()
        
           private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModel()
    }
    
    
    
        class NotificationsFragment : BaseFragment() {
        
           private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels({requireActivity()})
    
           private val viewModelx: HomeViewModel by activityViewModels
    
    
        
        }

> by using viewModels({requireActivity()}) getting instance not found.
```

**Update for Hilt**

```
   implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0"

   private val viewModelx: HomeViewModel by viewModels
```

the above-mentioned library has view models for injecting view models directly lazily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.android.sharedViewModel 

private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModel()
```

so solved this issue by using `viewModel()` in activity and `sharedViewModel<MyViewModel>()` in fragment class

Answer (score 2):

You need to give context in koin module

```
val appModule = module {
single { HomeViewModel (get()) } // it will get the context from Application Context
   
}
```

In activity you want to use  just use

```
private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by inject()
```

it will return the single instance of your viewModel

Comment: app context.? will manage scope and current instance of viewmodel.?

Comment: when we start the koin in Application
startKoin{
            androidContext(this@MyApplication)  //  it will get the context of Application
        }